# Why position absolute button are overlapping my content on smaller display?

Tags: html, css

I have simple question about my layout. Why are the black buttons on bottom of my screen overlapping my `position-absolute` text on smaller displays (in height)? I want to show scrollbar when there is not enough space for them.

So text have to be on center of screen and buttons on bottom of screen. Min height of content should be 100vh but if no space it should be more (on mobile). Buttons mustn't be overlapping text. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="sk">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/newStyle.css">
    <title> DOD</title></head>
    
    
<style>
html, body{
    height:100%;
}

.container-fluid{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.carousel-item{
    padding:20px;
}

#carouselExampleIndicators, .carousel-item{
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.carousel-bg{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: blur(5px);
}

.black-overlay{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}


.carousel-indicators li:hover {
    background-color: #6e43bf;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
    transition: background-color 300ms linear;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    text-indent: initial;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1);
    margin: 5px;

    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-shadow: none;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.carousel-content{
    margin-bottom:90px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.carousel-item{
    position: relative;
}




</style>    
<body>

<div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="black-overlay"></div>

    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

        <ol class="carousel-indicators d-flex flex-wrap">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0">
                <span>
                    Informačné technológie
                </span>
            </li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1">
                  <span>
                    Elektrotechnika
                </span>
            </li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2">
               <span>
                     Informačné a SieŤové technológie
                </span>
            </li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3">
              <span>
                    Strojárstvo
                </span>
            </li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="4">
              <span>
                    Mechatronika
                </span>
            </li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="5">
              <span class="d-none d-md-block">
                    Logistika
                </span>
                <i class="fas fa-wrench fa-2x d-md-none"></i>
            </li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="6">
              <span class="d-none d-md-block">
                    Technické lýceum
                </span>
                <i class="fas fa-wrench fa-2x d-md-none"></i>
            </li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="carousel-bg" style="background-image:url('assets/slider-electro.jpg')">

                </div>
                <div class="carousel-content">
                    <p>
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="carousel-bg" style="background-image:url('assets/slider-engineer.jpg')">

                </div>
                <div class="carousel-content">
                    <p>
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="carousel-bg" style="background-image: url('assets/slider-ist.jpg')">

                </div>
                <div class="carousel-content">
                    <p>
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                        their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                        their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                        purpose (injected humour and the like).
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because .carousel-indicator is also absolute:

add position: relative to .carousel-indicators class, and rearrange html code.
I think this is the result you're trying to achieve.

also edited classes (to fix alignment):
.carousel-item
.carousel-content
.carousel-item.active

---

changed min-height property added extra class for alignment. Mainly used flex properties to achieve this result.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="sk">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/newStyle.css">
    <title> DOD</title></head>

    <style>
    html, body{
  height:100%;
}

.container-fluid{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.extra-align {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.carousel-item{
  padding:20px;
}

#carouselExampleIndicators, .carousel-item{
/*   min-height: 100vh; */
}

.carousel-bg{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.black-overlay{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}


.carousel-indicators li:hover {
  background-color: #6e43bf;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
  transition: background-color 300ms linear;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  text-indent: initial;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1);
  margin: 5px;

  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-shadow: none;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.carousel-content{
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  display:flex;
  align-tems:center
}

.carousel-item.active{
  position: relative;
  display:flex!important;
  align-items:center;
}

.carousel-item{
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  position: relative;
}

    </style>
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
      <div class="black-overlay"></div>
    <div class="extra-align">
      <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="carousel-bg" style="background-image:url('assets/slider-electro.jpg')">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-content">
              <p>
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="carousel-bg" style="background-image:url('assets/slider-engineer.jpg')">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-content">
              <p>
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="carousel-bg" style="background-image: url('assets/slider-ist.jpg')">

            </div>
            <div class="carousel-content">
              <p>
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
                It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as
                their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in
                their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on
                purpose (injected humour and the like).
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <ol class="carousel-indicators d-flex flex-wrap">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0">
            <span>
              Informačné technológie
            </span>
          </li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1">
            <span>
              Elektrotechnika
            </span>
          </li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2">
            <span>
              Informačné a SieŤové technológie
            </span>
          </li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3">
            <span>
              Strojárstvo
            </span>
          </li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="4">
            <span>
              Mechatronika
            </span>
          </li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="5">
            <span class="d-none d-md-block">
              Logistika
            </span>
            <i class="fas fa-wrench fa-2x d-md-none"></i>
          </li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="6">
            <span class="d-none d-md-block">
              Technické lýceum
            </span>
            <i class="fas fa-wrench fa-2x d-md-none"></i>
          </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But now I can 't see buttons without scrolling on bigger resolutions

Comment: ok, so you need remove min height 100vh on some elements and  move buttons outside that parent. I'll edit.